# How can I see the ICC of the sim that I have inserted in my computer in the command line?

Tags: command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

How can I see this number with a command?

[image]

and tried with `netsh mbn sh interface` but it only shows me the imei

Comment: [Get IMEI, ICCID, IMSI, and telephone numbers for the MB device - Windows drivers | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/mobilebroadband/get-the-imei-iccid-imsi-and-telephone-numbers-for-the-mobile-broadband-device)?

Comment: Try *Start > Settings > Network & Internet > Cellular*. If you see there your carrier or card, click it and select "Advanced options". The data might be under Properties.

Comment: Check out the script listed here that may help you without having to recreate the wheel: https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/3605-get-cellularadapter. I cannot emulate this configuration to test and confirm it works myself for you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can find

```
netsh mbn show read interface=*
```

should provide more information, including the SIM ICC Id.